# feature `tag` filters not working properly in parallel execution

Tags: karate

when i ran with `@smoke` tag, its looping for all features files which are not have `@smoke` tag and printing `skipped` features files in console as below -

```
runner.KarateRunnerTest - <<skip>> feature 362 of 1436:
runner.KarateRunnerTest - <<skip>> feature 363 of 1436:
```

ideally, it should iterate how many features we've with `@smoke` tag.
i'm using `Runner` class for parallel execution -

```
Runner.parallel(getClass(), threadCount, karateOutputPath);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is fine and a change in behavior in 0.9.0 onwards. Karate will scan ALL files.

Check again, it will not execute what is shown as `<<skip>>` and they will not appear in the report.

Comment: Yes, it wasn't appeared in reports. but, its looping total features count. let say in features classpath we've 1500 features but `@smoke` tag features we've 20 only.

here loop having 1500 instead of 20 features.

Comment: @Mr.Venkat so what's the problem ? are you trying to test or only worried about "looping" and too many log lines ?

Comment: because of too many logs on console came to knew its looping issue.

Comment: @Mr.Venkat it is NOT an issue.

Comment: framework generating too many .log files(under surefire-reports folder) which are not part of execution, i mean skipped feature files. hence causing slow while generateReport().

is there any way to stop creating .log files which are from skipped features?

Comment: @Mr.Venkat "causing slow" ? what do you mean. how slow, can you measure ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186910/discussion-between-mr-venkat-and-peter-thomas).

Comment: @Mr.Venkat no we shall not. seriously this is not an issue. the log files are not used to generate the report. nobody else has complained about it. you are wasting your time when you should be focused on writing tests. if you want to change karate, contribute code - it is open source :)